# react-lottie, unable to pass props for animationData

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rxjs, lottie

i'm new to using react-lottie and I'm trying to build a class component to allow me to pass in a path to a .json file and a href link. I'm about to pass the link through props, but I'm having difficulty passing the the path and getting the following error:

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lottie from 'react-lottie';

class SocialLinks extends Component {
    state = { isStopped: false };

    render() {

        const defaultOptions = {
            loop: true,
            autoplay: false,
            animationData: { this.props.icon },
            rendererSettings: {
                preserveAspectRatio: 'xMidYMid slice'
            }
        };

        return (
            <span
                className="Social_links"
                onMouseEnter={() => this.setState({ isStopped: false })}
                onMouseLeave={() => this.setState({ isStopped: true })}
            >
                <a href={this.props.link}>
                    <Lottie
                        options={defaultOptions}
                        isStopped={this.state.isStopped}
                        width={40}
                    />
                </a>
            </span>
        );
    }
}

export default SocialLinks;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the double braces.

use:

```
animationData: { this.props.icon }
```

or

```
animationData: { icon : this.props.icon }
```

Comment: I tried animationData: { this.props.icon } but got the issue: Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'. So I took out the 'this' and got an error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," [expected { props.icon }, where is . is]

I also tried { icon : this.props.icon }, and it didn't load anything

Comment: @HarshDesai why did you change the code? you should post that as an updated. Also now you have changed "defaultOptions " as a function instead of an object. what exactly do you need? I have checked the react-lottie examples , the options is a object not function. https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie/blob/master/src/stories/lottie-control.js

Comment: sorry you're right. I should have done it as an update. I thought my changing it to a function would have helped with passing the props. I will change it back to what I previously had.

Comment: do you think it would be easier to pass the entire obj as a prop rather than the different attributes?

Comment: @HarshDesai now what problem are you facing with the current code ?

Comment: I can't pass the path to the json file to animationData: { this.props.icon }

Comment: @HarshDesai well looking at the examples of that lib, i'm not surprised. there is some JSON data is being passed to as animationData in those example, are you passing the same in the icon prop?

Comment: @HarshDesai look at https://github.com/chenqingspring/react-lottie/blob/master/src/stories/pinjump.json

Comment: Yea, I have a json file for an animation of my own. I'm trying to pass the path to the file in the animationData. I have 8 different json files, I have been able to build the lottie components for each one individually, but I rather just have 1 component and pass the different href and file as props.

Comment: @HarshDesai this is not possible, if the component is expecting the data, it means you need to import the data and pass to the component. a path will not work. check for if exist and prop which accepts the paths.